# Too many DML rows: 10001(bulk update)

Tags: apex, class, field-update

when I try to run the code below I am getting this error: 'Too many DML rows: 10001'. The object that I am trying to update is one of the main object in the org. so it has multiples triggers, workflows, etc. and one API that runs all day long. I am trying to update 29000 records. can anybody please tell me why i am getting this error or if something is wrong with the code. I will appreciate any help!

Class code:

```
 public class updateNRProdObject{

  public Decimal Debug{ get; set; }     

  public void updateObject(){


  List<NRProducts__c> products = [SELECT id  FROM NRProducts__c WHERE  Active__c = true];
  Debug = products.size();

  for(NRProducts__c p : products){

     p.Active__c=false;

  }

  update products ;

 }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot update more than 10000 records in a single transaction.

It looks like you may be doing this in a VF page so you will have to write your VF page to check the status of a batch every so often and then do what you require when it is completed. You can use `<apex:actionPoller>` in your page and run a method to query the AsyncApexJob object to see if the the batch has been completed or not.

Please note the examples may need some tweaking as I modified existing code to use your example. I may have missed something....

**EXAMPLE PAGE**

```
<apex:page controller="YOUR CONTROLLER" showHeader="true" sidebar="true" cache="false">

    <apex:outPutPanel layout="block" id="main_panel" rendered="{!!fatal_error}">

        <apex:outPutPanel layout="block" id="job_start" >

            <apex:outPutPanel layout="block" id="job_start_processing" rendered="{!AND(start_polling,NOT(job_is_done))}" styleClass="ctr">
                <div class="ctr">
                    <h1>In Progress - Please Wait</h1>
                    <br /><br />
                </div>

                <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.processing_small)}"/>
            </apex:outPutPanel>

            <apex:outPutPanel layout="block" id="job_start_button" rendered="{!!start_polling}" styleClass="ctr">           
                    <h1>Click 'Start Process' to begin</h1>
                    <br /><br />

                <apex:commandButton action="{!run_process}" value="Start Process" reRender="job_start,msgs"/>
            </apex:outPutPanel>


            <apex:actionPoller action="{!poll_for_completion}" reRender="job_start,job_stop,msgs" interval="5"/>

        </apex:outPutPanel>


        <apex:outPutPanel layout="block" id="job_stop" styleClass="ctr">

            <apex:outPutPanel layout="block" id="job_done" rendered="{!AND(job_is_done,ISBLANK(job_error_message))}">

                <div class="ctr">
                    <h1>Complete</h1>
                    <br /><br />
                </div>

                <apex:commandButton action="{!restart_page}" value="Reset Page" rerender="msgs"/>
            </apex:outPutPanel> 


            <apex:outPutPanel layout="block" id="job_error" rendered="{!AND(job_is_done,NOT(ISBLANK(job_error_message)))}">

                <div class="ctr">
                    <h1>Error</h1>
                    <br />
                    <p>Message: &nbsp; {!job_error_message}</p>
                    <br />
                </div>

                <apex:commandButton action="{!restart_page}" value="Reset Page" rerender="msgs"/>
            </apex:outPutPanel> 

        </apex:outPutPanel>


    </apex:outPutPanel> 
</apex:page>
```

**EXAMPLE CONTROLLER**

```
public with sharing class YOUR CONTROLLER NAME {

    private AsyncApexJob[] jobs;
    @TestVisible private ApexClass[] apex_class;
    @TestVisible private Map<ID,AsyncApexJob> previous_jobs;

    public boolean job_is_done  {get;set;}
    public boolean start_polling {get;set;}
    public boolean fatal_error{get;set;}
    public string job_error_message {get;set;}


    public YOUR CONTROLLER NAME(){


        job_is_done = false;

        apex_class = [Select ID, Name From ApexClass Where Name = 'CLASS NAME'];

        if(apex_class.isEmpty()) return;

        //get previous jobs - so we can kinda tell if ours has ran
        previous_jobs = New Map<ID,AsyncApexJob>([Select ApexClassID, JobType, MethodName, Status 
                                                From AsyncApexJob where JobType = 'BatchApex' 
                                                AND ApexClassID = :apex_class[0].id
                                                AND CreatedByID = :userInfo.getUserID()
                                                AND CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:1]);



    }

    public void run_process(){


        try{
            example_Batch b = New example_Batch();
            database.executeBatch(b);
        }catch(exception e){
            job_error_message = e.getMessage();
        }
        //start_polling = true;
        job_is_done = true;



    }

    public void poll_for_completion(){

        if(job_is_done || start_polling == false) return;

        AsyncApexJob[] tmp = [Select ID, ApexClassID, JobType, MethodName, Status, ExtendedStatus 
                                                From AsyncApexJob 
                                                where JobType = 'BatchApex' 
                                                AND ApexClassID = :apex_class[0].id
                                                AND CreatedByID = :userInfo.getUserID()
                                                AND (ID NOT IN :previous_jobs.keySet())
                                                AND CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:1
                                                AND (Status = 'Completed' OR Status = 'Failed')];


        if(!tmp.isEmpty() || test.isRunningTest()){
            job_is_done = true;

            if(!test.isRunningTest() && tmp[0].Status == 'Failed'){
                job_error_message = tmp[0].ExtendedStatus;
            }
        }





    }

    public pagereference restart_page(){

        pageReference pr = New PageReference('/apex/YOUR PAGE');
        pr.setRedirect(true);
        return pr;

    }




}
```

In order to do what you are wanting to do you will need to write a batch class to perform the updates. The code would look something like:

```
global class example_Batch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{




    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

        String query = 'SELECT id  FROM NRProducts__c WHERE  Active__c = true';

        if(test.isRunningTest()){
            query += ' LIMIT 200';
        }

        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope) {

        Decimal Debug = products.size();

          for(NRProducts__c p : (NRPProducts__c[])scope){

             p.Active__c=false;

          }


        database.update(scope,false);

    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

    }

}
```

Then to execute it you would use

```
example_Batch b = New example_Batch();
database.executeBatch(b);
```

Comment: Hello Eric, thank you for your response. I am using a vf Page with a single button. If I am not wrong i have to create this batch and execute the batch with the button making an instance. I've never used <apex:actionpoiler> so how do i check the status of the batch?  Thank you in advance

Comment: @Carlos - See updated answer

Comment: Eric, thank you so much man! i really appreciate your help!!

Comment: Eric, I was able to modified the code and I tested it in sandbox and i worked perfectly. Tonight I will run it in Production. Question for you: should I increase the ' LIMIT 200' if so what is the max limit i can use for this batch. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Carlos - The limit is only there for test methods. You cannot return more than 200 records in a batch during a test method so this will limit the results in cases where you have created more than 200 records. For non-test methods the query is not limited at all

Comment: ok thank you for explaining this. The last question: in order to update the 29000 records how many times do i need to click the button? sorry for all the question i am just trying to understand this approach.

Comment: Once. When you click the button the batch will run. It will be complete after all records in the query have been processed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16760/discussion-between-carlos-and-eric).

Comment: Eric, the test class for batch got 100% but for the controller I tried this:`@itest ... batchUpdateNRProdActiveField batch = new batchUpdateNRProdActiveField();
     database.executeBatch(batch );   
      Test.startTest();
     batchActiveField_Validation_Controller b = new batchActiveField_Validation_Controller ();      b.run_process();
b.poll_for_completion();    
       b.restart_page();   
     Test.stopTest(); ` I am getting 74%, basically is an instance of controller class. I don't know how to write a test class for this type of class. whenever u can please help me! Thank u in advance!

Comment: @Carlos - Please ask this in a new question. A search for testing batch classes will also help.